# VSCode auto-open replace field in Find & Replace

Tags: visual-studio-code

When the Find & Replace box is opened, the default view is to hide the replace field.

[image]

So whenever I want to replace something, I have to click the left arrow to "Toggle Replace Mode". Is there a way to set Replace Mode to be active by default? There's really no negative to having it open, as pressing enter goes to the next match in both modes, and having it open by default allows one to tab into it without having to use the mouse at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, it will open the find widget with the replace field open.  Or it will open the replace field of the find widget if it isn't already open without the replace field showing.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The key binding for that is `editor.action.startFindReplaceAction`, so I just rebound that to ctrl+f and unbound the find binding and it works perfectly.

Comment: If you're looking to do the same for "Search: find in files", the command to use instead is "Search: replace in files" (workbench.action.replaceInFiles)